# How to effectively write named queries JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have named queries which looks like the following:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "table.getvalues", query = "select p from table p where p.a = :a and p.b = :b and p.c = :c order by id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "table.getvalueswhencisnull", query = "select p from table p where p.a = :a and p.b = :b and p.c is null order by id")
})
```

The only difference between 2 named queries is the the value of the c,c can be null and the syntax of the sql query differs only because of that.

Is there a way where I can club both the statements effectively?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
select p from table p where p.a = :a and p.b = :b and (p.c is null or p.c=:c) order by id
```

Comment: But if the c value is provided in the get request,I don't want results with c as null.

Comment: if you want all values without null values, use IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this filter does a conditional selection.

```
...AND (p.c=:c OR (:c IS NULL and p.c IS NULL))...
```